# What Does This Target And Source Means Exactly In Git Diff Command. I am Totally Confused in Understanding Them

Tags: git, git-diff

According To Documentation a Here Means Target And b Means Source, But Some Saying That a is Source And b is Destination or Target. Totally Confused Who is Correct And How To Distinguish in Between Them.

Answer (score 0):

The only place that `git diff` documentation refers to "source" or "target" is in reference to copy or rename status and (indirectly, to copy or rename again) in the `-l` option.  Meanwhile, the `a/` and `b/` prefixes are documented as the default values for the `--src-prefix` and `--dst-prefix` options.  See [the `git diff` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

When you *run* `git diff`, you choose two commits to compare:

```
git diff commit1 commit2
```

or you may use your working tree or Git's index as one of the two commits, e.g.,

```
git diff commit1
```

(which uses the working tree's contents as if it were the *`commit2`* to compare), or you may compare the contents of Git's index to the contents of your working tree:

```
git diff
```

(here Git's index acts as *`commit1`* and your working tree takes the place of *`commit2`*).  Again, see the documentation for the complete list,<sup>1</sup> but note that in each case, we're comparing two entire commits, or things that are treated "as if" they were commits.

The diff command then treats the two commits (or commit stand-ins) as if they were two complete snapshots of all files, and plays a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference) with these files.  We, by which I mean humans, wish to avoid talking about these two commits (or stand-ins) by raw Git commit hash ID.  That's because hash IDs are too ugly and otherwise horrible for humans to deal with, plus there's a problem if we're using a stand-in that isn't actually a commit (because then there *is no hash ID* <sup>2</sup>).  So, instead of using hash IDs, Git will use a *source prefix* `a/` and a *destination prefix* `b/`.

A source prefix, of course, implies that `a/` is the *source*, and that is the meaning of the word *source* in the documentation.  A destination is also (though somewhat weakly) a [target](https://www.thesaurus.net/destination#anchor-target), so if `b/` means the destination, it also means the target.

---

<sup>1</sup>As a bit of a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring), `git diff` can also produce a *combined diff*.  We will ignore this case entirely for this answer.

<sup>2</sup>The hash ID of a commit depends on everything inside that commit, including the date-and-time at which the commit was made.  Since a thing that isn't a commit isn't a commit with a date-and-time-stamp, the best we could get is the theoretical commit that we *would* have gotten, had we made a commit *right now*.  There's no point though, because that theoretical hash ID will have no further use: by the time we're ready to use it, time has moved on, and it's no longer what time it was then.  Plus, of course, as humans, we don't *want* to use hash IDs anyway!